# using doubly linked list to process a text

Tags: java, string, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I have to read a paragraph containing words from an input file. then create a doubly linked list containing the distinct words read, where the words of the same length are placed in the same list, in ascending order.

So i tried to create an array of doubly linked list, I know how to add the words but I can't sort them in ascending order.(we have to sort the words while adding them, not sorting the text then adding.)

```
int x = max(s);
DoublyLinkedList[] list = new DoublyLinkedList[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i] = new DoublyLinkedList();
        }

public static void m(DoublyLinkedList[] list, String s) {

        String[] s1 = s.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            list[s1[i].length()].addLast(s1[i]);

        }
    }

    public static int max(String s) {
        String[] s1 = s.split(" ");
        int max = s1[1].length();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            if (s1[i].length() > max) {
                max = s1[i].length();
            }
        }
        return max + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void insertAtRightSpot(DoublyLinekdList list, String s){
   int i = 0;
   boolean inserted = false;
   while(i<list.length()){
      if(list.get(i).compareTo(s) < 0){
         i++;
      } else {
         list.insertAt(s, i); 
         inserted = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (!inserted) list.addLast(s);
}
```

Try insertAtRightSpot(list[s1[i].length()], s1[i]) instead of list[s1[i].length()].addLast(s1[i])
The Method searches for the first Element that is not smaller that the one you want to insert and inserts it right before

Comment: please describe your answer as much as possible

Comment: @Linusk I used your idea and changed it a little but it is still not working any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: public static void addSorted(DoublyLinkedList list, String s) {
  String s1 = (String) (list.getFirst());
  String s2 = (String) (list.getLast());
  if (s1 == null) {
   list.addFirst(s);
  } else if (s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s) <= 0) {
   list.addFirst(s);
  } else if (s2.compareToIgnoreCase(s) >= 0) {
   list.addLast(s);
  }

  else {
   int i = 0;
   String s3 = (String) (list.get(i));
   while (s3.compareToIgnoreCase(s) > 0) {
    i++;
    break;
   }
   list.add(s, i);
  }
 }